# Odd HashMap Counter Behavior

Tags: java, if-statement, hashmap, jlist

I have this code which applies a counter to each item on the list. When the item reaches a certain number it is moved from jList3 to jList 1.

```
public Map<Object, Integer> buttonMap = new HashMap<Object, Integer>();
    private void jButton5ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {  

    Integer counter = null;
    int[] selection = jList3.getSelectedIndices();
     for (int i = 0; i < selection.length; i++){
        Object selString = jList3.getModel().getElementAt(selection[i]);
       counter = buttonMap.get(selString);      
        if(counter == null ) {           
            buttonMap.put(selString, new Integer(1));     
        }                                                                                                      
        else {
        buttonMap.put(selString, new Integer(counter.intValue() + 1)); 
        }           
        System.out.println(selString + " has been clicked " + buttonMap.get(selString) + " times.");                                      

       try{
        if (counter == 4){                          
           listModel2.removeElement(selString);
            listModel.addElement(selString);                             
        }
       }
        catch (NullPointerException npe1) {
        npe1.getMessage();
              }                                                                  
        }                                                   
  }
```

The behavior comes in the `if counter == 4` section.

It works fine but here is the weird part that I need help understanding

If I am counting up two items at the same time and they both reach the number that moves them on the same button click.

-It moves 1 of the items

-It does not count up on the other

-Instead it adds +1 to the counter of a non highlighted item

Example:

I am counting on list item 1 and 2, they both reach the max number, 1 gets moved 2 stays put(no increase in count) and item 3 gets +1 to counter

Comment: How is your counting up logic implemented? Do you have multiple threads? Because the code you have shown above is not thread safe.

Comment: why does everything have the same key ?

Comment: @Perception added all code, so just threading would fix it?

Comment: @harper89 - ok good. Quick question, is listModel2 the same as jList3.getModel()?

Comment: @perception Yes. I guess my big question is what causes it up +1 something that is not highlighted? And to everyone sorry about the nameing, this is just something I have been doing on the side, so I do what I want :)

Comment: @harper89 - well looks like Maurice posted an answer already. You can see mine as well below!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you remove an element from jList3, the elements that follow are shifted.
I would sort the selection array and scan it in reverse order.

```
...
int[] selection = jList3.getSelectedIndices();
Arrays.sort(selection);
for (int i = selection.length; --i >= 0; ){
...
```

UPDATE: the sorting is not required, because the array returned by getSelectedIndices() already is

Comment: ahhh, I see, if I addElement then Remove I dont get a weird vote just an out of bounds exception

Comment: @ Maurice if I ran each item in its own thread? woudl that also solve the problem or is that to much?

Comment: j/w thanks again the fact they are shifting solved the confusion

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are modifying one of your model lists in the same loop as in which you are querying it. If you were using an iterator you would actually get a concurrent modification exception, but as it is you are using specific indexing. In either case your logic is now wrong because the indexes you were relying on to query the list have changed. You can sort your *selection* array in descending order and keep your code the way it is, but I think it will be cleaner and more maintainable to modify your source array after the loop is done, like so:

```
...
    System.out.println(selString + " has been clicked " + buttonMap.get(selString) + " times.");

    if (counter == 4) {
        listModel.addElement(selString);
    }
}

for(Object o : listModel) {
    listModel2.removeElement(o);
}
```